# Using SQL sub queries in BETWEEN clause for dates

Tags: mysql, sql

What is wrong with this multiple select SQL in MySQL:

```
select *
from license
where license.expirydate between (
   (select monthrange.monthstart from monthrange where id = 1)
   and
   (select monthrange.monthend from monthrange where id = 1)
)
```

Comment: **HOW** is this not working? syntax error? wrong results?

Comment: @MarcB It was a syntax error, had to remove the outer parentheses as per Gordon's answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your query:

```
select *
from license
where license.expirydate between ((select monthrange.monthstart from monthrange where id = 1) and 
                                  (select monthrange.monthend from monthrange where id = 1)
                                 )
```

The arguments to `between` should not be in parentheses.  Try this:

```
select *
from license
where license.expirydate between (select monthrange.monthstart from monthrange where id = 1) and 
                                 (select monthrange.monthend from monthrange where id = 1)
```

Of course, you can also express this as a `join`.  This answer is only meant to comment on the syntax error:

```
select l.*
from license l join
     monthrange m
     on l.expirydate between m.monthstart and m.monthend and
        m.id = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, much appreciated.